# Truncate 16-bit number in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

Given a `[15:0]` number (there is no fractional part, only integer). How do I truncate the lower two bits `[1:0]` and round it off to the closest possible value? Consider a case where no overflow happens. I need to do it in Verilog.

```
input [15:0] A;
output [13:0] B;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement rounding, you'll need an incrementer (add 1) for the round-up case.

Let's assume the rounding behavior you want is as follows:

- lsb's = 0,0: truncate (round down)
- lsb's = 0,1: truncate (round down)
- lsb's = 1,0: round up
- lsb's = 1,1: round up

The Verilog would look something like this:

```
wire [15:0] A;
wire [13:0] Y;
wire [0:0]  round_up;

    assign round_up = A[1:0] >= 2'b10;
    assign Y = A[15:2] + round_up;
```

The sharp-eyed among you will see that the increment select can be simplified as:

```
    assign round_up = A[1];
```

And you can suppress the wraparound case with one more trick, giving:

```
    assign round_up = A[1] && ~(A[15:2] == 14'h3fff);    // catch the wrap case
    assign Y = A[15:2] + round_up;
```

I'm sure there's other ways to code this, but they will all include at least the adder and the overflow range check to prevent wrap (that is, saturation.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
    wire [15:0] C;
    assign C = A+2;        //rounding offset
    assign B = {C[15:2]};  //drop 2 trailing bits
```

A=1  => C=3 => B=0

A=2  => C=4 => B=1

A=3  => C=5 => B=1

This would of course round up on a tie; to round down, change the 2 to 1. For the highest values, this will overflow (ie 0xFFFD, 0xFFFE and 0xFFFF will output 0x000). If this isn't wanted, extend C to 17 bits and catch the overflow.